# Javascript, GruntJS, Declaring a global object and concatenating partials together

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, javascript, gruntjs

I'm not the most experienced Javascript programmer, and have recently started a web-app project that is larger than the scope of stuff that I'm used to (mostly used to doing company websites, etc.)

The JS that runs the app has become unmanageable as a single file, so I decided it would be better to split it up into smaller functions and use gruntJS to concatenate everything together for me.

I have been using the modular design pattern on the main app, but I'm a little confused now that I've split it up into smaller chunks. Take the following illustration:

```
var myProject = (function() {

    var init = function() {

        effects.widgetColor('lighter'); // this doesn't work
        login(); // this doesn't work

        myProject.effects.widgetColor('lighter'); // this does work
        myProject.login(); // this does work

    }

    return {

        init: init

    };

})();

myProject.effects = (function() {

    // effects

})();

myProject.login = (function() {

    // login stuff

})();

$(document).ready(function() {

    init(); // this doesn't work
    myProject.init() // this does work

});
```

My question is how best to add these functions to the 'myProject' object? I'm sure this is a simple fundamental concept that I just haven't learned yet.

Thanks :)

Comment: just put everything which you think has a separate logic into a single js file, and concatenate them together with grunt-contrib-concat

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use submodules. There is a similar question asked here

[Pattern for Javascript Module Pattern and Sub-Module Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083409/pattern-for-javascript-module-pattern-and-sub-module-initialization)